# Reorder JSON in python

Tags: python, json

Hello I got a JSON in python :

```
{'id': {'0': 'AAPL', '1': 'MIC', '2': 'GOO', '3': 'AMZ'}, 'brand': {'0': 'apple', '1': 'microsoft', '2': 'google', '3': 'amazon'}}
```

I need to reorder it to have this JSON :

```
{'0': { id:'AAPL', brand:'apple'}, 1 : {id:'MIC', brand:'microsoft', ....}
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group by the inner dictionaries keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {'id': {'0': 'AAPL', '1': 'MIC', '2': 'GOO', '3': 'AMZ'}, 'brand': {'0': 'apple', '1': 'microsoft', '2': 'google', '3': 'amazon'}}

result = defaultdict(dict)
for k1, v1 in d.items():
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        result[k2][k1] = v2

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'0': {'id': 'AAPL', 'brand': 'apple'}, '1': {'id': 'MIC', 'brand': 'microsoft'}, '2': {'id': 'GOO', 'brand': 'google'}, '3': {'id': 'AMZ', 'brand': 'amazon'}})
```

Or if you want a normal `dict` type:

```
print(dict(result))
```

**Output:**

```
{'0': {'id': 'AAPL', 'brand': 'apple'}, '1': {'id': 'MIC', 'brand': 'microsoft'}, '2': {'id': 'GOO', 'brand': 'google'}, '3': {'id': 'AMZ', 'brand': 'amazon'}}
```

**Note:** `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`, so the latter option is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution. Know for the future that you are expected to show your efforts in solving the problem when asking a question. You can't always expect everything done for you.

```
data = {'id': {'0': 'AAPL', '1': 'MIC', '2': 'GOO', '3': 'AMZ'}, 'brand': {'0': 'apple', '1': 'microsoft', '2': 'google', '3': 'amazon'}}

result = {}

for k in data['id'].keys():
  result[k] = {'id': data['id'][k], 'brand': data['brand'][k]}
```

You can also do this with one line:

```
data = {'id': {'0': 'AAPL', '1': 'MIC', '2': 'GOO', '3': 'AMZ'}, 'brand': {'0': 'apple', '1': 'microsoft', '2': 'google', '3': 'amazon'}}

result = {k : {'id': data['id'][k], 'brand': data['brand'][k]} for k in data['id'].keys()}
```

In both of these examples, the output of `print(result)` would be:

```
{'0': {'id': 'AAPL', 'brand': 'apple'}, '1': {'id': 'MIC', 'brand': 'microsoft'}, '2': {'id': 'GOO', 'brand': 'google'}, '3': {'id': 'AMZ', 'brand': 'amazon'}}
```

Comment: Using `dict` as a variable name just shadows the builtin function. I would call it something else...

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your json_input is your json.

```
result = {}
for i,(_id, _brand) in enumerate(zip(json_input["id"].values(), json_input["brand"].values())): 
     result.update({i: {"brand": _brand, "id": _id}})
```